# How to remove arrow before image in new line for dynamic data?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I Have a dynamic content rendered from angular that generates a follow HTML:

```
<div class="complted" *ngFor="let step of letStep1to7; let i = index; let first = first">
    <table>
      <td><img width="60px" [ngClass]="{lastArrow: first }" src="../../assets/images/arr.png" alt=""></td>
      <td class="steps" [ngClass]="{ last: last }">
        <img class="completeimg" src={{step.img}} alt="">
        <p class="card-text1"> Step {{i+1}}: Completed</p>
        <p class="card-text1">{{step.ReturnDisplayC}}</p>
        <p class="card-text1"><b>Date:</b> {{step.ReturnStatus}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">{{step.ReturnStatus}}</p>
      </td>

    </table>
  </div>
```

I want to remove arrow before image for this dynamic data.

How can I remove arrow image for next line of data as highlighted in below image?

[image: want to remove starting arrow from new line]

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot with inspect element so I can identify the class name of the arrow or its parent class name?

Comment: Please take a look i just attached screenshot with inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the td for arrow image.

```
<div class="complted" *ngFor="let step of letStep1to7; let i = index; let first = first">
    <table>
      <td class="steps" [ngClass]="{ last: last }">
        <div style="display: inline;">
          <img class="completeimg" src={{step.img}} alt="">
          <p class="card-text1"> Step {{i+1}}: Completed</p>
          <p class="card-text1">{{step.ReturnDisplayC}}</p>
          <p class="card-text1"><b>Date:</b> {{step.ReturnStatus}}</p>
          <p class="card-text">{{step.ReturnStatus}}</p>
        </div>
        <img width="60px" [ngClass]="{lastArrow: first }" src="../../assets/images/arr.png" alt="">
      </td>    
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and time but if i remove this td for arrow image it will remove all the arrows in the div i just want to remove arrow from the new line as shown in image, later if more data will come in 3rd line, than first arrow in new line should be there

Comment: I changed the code. It removes <td> for every 5th item.

Comment: Yes it can help, but what if 6 or 7 elements will come in the first row? Because data is dynamic so it can take any number of elements in any row

Comment: I think it needs some unknown trick.

Comment: I think the only way is to put the arrow image with pc image  in the same td.

Comment: tried this as well but no luck :(